# Android Navigation Drawer without a profile header

Tags: navigation, android, header, drawer

I am implementing the navigation drawer in my app but the problem is that my app has nothing to do with user's profiles. This makes me wonder as to what should I place in the header section of the navigation drawer.

My app needs the navigation drawer because there are multiple pages or 'modes' which the user would want to switch between. The core purpose is served by listing all the actions but these actions look too far up, and they look bare.

Should I go for some decoration like app icon, title, etc.?

Here's how the app looks without the header:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try and lower the list to below where the header bar would normally be. See screenshot below.

Your list might look bare because you do not use icons like in most of the examples of the Material Design guidelines.

You might want to reconsider not having a user profile. Having a clear indication of for whom the user is working in the application is a good thing to have. This does not have to be a complex user profile. Maybe just a name and a greeting. "Welcome back, Usman" for example.

[image]